# new environment issue when typing urdu text

Tags: latex, xelatex

I am writing some text in the Urdu language as question and answer style.

Following is a minimal example

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in, paperwidth=5.5in, paperheight=8.5in] {geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,color, xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{parskip}


\setmainlanguage{urdu}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\parskip 0in

\setmainfont[Path=/Users/imdad/fonts/]{Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq.ttf}

\newcounter{uques}[chapter]

\newenvironment{question}[2][سوال \stepcounter{uques} \arabic{uques}:]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep\bfseries \noindent #1] #2\newline \textbf{جواب:} }   {\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{اردو ٹیکسٹ}    
\begin{question}{آپ کیا کام کرتے ہو؟}
    میرا چھوٹا سا کمپیوٹر اور موبائل اسسریز کا کام ہے۔
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

The new environment works fine but questions number does not update automatically. In English documents, it works fine (question number increments automatically updated). Please guide and if possible improve the question answer style in the Urdu language.

Comment: I checked the roman style numbers are working but Arabic style is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [Jameel Noori Nastaleeq](http://www.urdujahan.com/font.html) font contains only the EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGITS from U+06F0 upwards, while the Urdu-language support in polyglossia uses ARABIC-INDIC DIGITS from U+0660 upwards. That might well be a bug in polyglossia. With TexLive 2016 `gloss-urdu.ldf` contains:

```
\def\urdunumber#1{%
  \if@western@numerals
    \number#1%
  \else
    %%FIXME use farsidigits instead???
    \protect\arabicdigits{\number#1}%
  \fi}
```

This enables us to build a fixed defintion for `\urdunumber` (without support for western-arabic numerals:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{urdu}

% use EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGITS from U+0F60 upwards
\def\urdunumber#1{\protect\farsidigits{\number#1}}

\setmainfont{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\newcounter{uques}[chapter]

\newenvironment{question}[2][سوال \stepcounter{uques} \arabic{uques}:]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep\bfseries \noindent #1] #2\newline \textbf{جواب:} }   {\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{اردو ٹیکسٹ}    
\begin{question}{آپ کیا کام کرتے ہو؟}
    میرا چھوٹا سا کمپیوٹر اور موبائل اسسریز کا کام ہے۔
\end{question}

\begin{question}{آپ کیا کام کرتے ہو؟}
    میرا چھوٹا سا کمپیوٹر اور موبائل اسسریز کا کام ہے۔
\end{question}

\begin{question}{آپ کیا کام کرتے ہو؟}
    میرا چھوٹا سا کمپیوٹر اور موبائل اسسریز کا کام ہے۔
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, dear. The main font required is "Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq.ttf". Under this fond numbers are not printing.

Comment: @itfeature.com Would the above screen shot be what you expected if it were using the right font?

Comment: Somewhat like the screenshot but numbers are not produced when \setmainfont{Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq.ttf}.
The following link is the screenshot.
http://prntscr.com/k1ywe6

Comment: @itfeature.com Please see the updated answer for an actual solution.

Comment: I also found another solution, but there is a minor issue. Could not understand how to resolve it. I am asking it as a new question.